# Top five names with score

Tags: python

I have a programming challenge at school where i make a game and at the end, it prints the top five scores of all time. I have been able to get it to print the top five scores but I dont know how to make it print the score with the username along it. The code is:

```
with open("login.csv") as f:
    print(" ")
    print(" ")
    print("Usernames and scores:")
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    scores=(row[-1] for row in reader)
    topscore=sorted(scores, reverse=True)
    top5=topscore[:5]
    print(top5)
```

The output i get is:

```
Usernames and scores:
['82', '80', '66', '64', '62']
```

My desired output however is:

```
Usernames and scores:
Dylan, 82
f, 80
Farai, 66
Dylan, 64
Dylan, 62
```

Any help
Dylan

I missed this out but the columns go name, password, score. Sorry for missing that out guys.

Comment: What column is the usernames in?

Comment: The username is in column 0 (The first column). I have updated the question to show the order of the columns that i missed out in the question. Silly mistake on my behalf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the rows together with a key function that allows the sorting to be based on the last column:

```
with open("login.csv") as f:
    print(" ")
    print(" ")
    print("Usernames and scores:")
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    topscore=sorted(reader, key=lambda row: int(row[-1]), reverse=True)
    top5=topscore[:5]
    print('\n'.join(', '.join((username, score)) for username, _, score in top5))
```

Comment: This works almost perfectly. This isn't your fault but in the post i forgot to say that  the columns go in the order: name, password, score. I'm not too sure how to make it for only name and score and i have been playing around with the code you posted. Do you know how you would change it to print only name and score. :D

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're selecting only the score through the list comprehension. 
Assuming that the CSV is something like < username > , < score >, maybe the following will work?

```
with open("login.csv") as f:
    print(" ")
    print(" ")
    print("Usernames and scores:")
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    scores=(row for row in reader)
    topscore=sorted(scores, reverse=True)
    for score in topscores:
        print(score[0] +",\t" + score[1])
```

Comment: It seems like the score is the last (second?) element in the row, so this would sort by name (or whatever is the first) instead.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something about the reading of a CSV file (never had the chance to work with it): if I open a file, doesn't it store in an unspecified number of tuples what I have in the file (ie, position 0 the user, position 1 the score)?

Comment: That's right, but since the first position seems to be the username -- or at least _not_ the score, as OP is using `row[-1]` to get that -- your approach will not sort by the score. You need to use a `key` function.